# How to add an eventListener to div display style in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to trigger a function when a div is shown in React to make a Highcharts chart resize to fit its parent element. Highcharts doesn't automatically resize when a parent element resizes - there is a solution to make this work here https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=39587, but it's a couple of years old and I'm trying to make it work with React hooks.

```js
  const [toggleDiv, setToggleDiv] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleToggle = (): void => {
    setToggleDiv(!toggleDiv);
  };

  const sideBar = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const div = sideBar.current;
  if (div) {
    div.addEventListener('transitionend', () => { // this doesn't get called like it says it should in the linked article
      if (Highcharts.charts[0] !== undefined) {
        Highcharts.charts[0].reflow();
      }
    });
  }
...
    <>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={handleToggle}
        style={{ float: 'left' }}
      >
        Hide div
      </button>
      <div
        style={{
          width: '200px', border: '1px blue solid', float: 'left', display: toggleDiv ? 'inline' : 'none',
        }}
        ref={sideBar}
      />
      <div>
        <HighchartsReact
          highcharts={Highcharts}
          options={options}
          {...props}
        />
      </div>
    </>
```

The problem with my code is that the event listener callback never gets called. How can I call `Highcharts.charts[0].reflow();` when the div display property changes between `'none'` and `'inline'`?

Comment: Hi @Mr. Robot, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? You can start from: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qkjsqz?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the "toggleDiv" value with a useEffect hook.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  Highcharts.charts[0].reflow()
}, [toggleDiv])

//This function gets called everytime toggleDiv changes
```

Keep in mind that when you want to access the actual value of the state you always want to do this:

```js
setToggleDiv(prevState => !prevState);
```

And not this:

```js
setToggleDiv(!toggleDiv); // <-- This is bad
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I need to listen for a DOM element being removed and shown though - the only way I will be able to tell wether it's present is if the class name is in the DOM.

Comment: But it's exactly what you want.
You use the toggleDiv property to set the css property to display: none or inline.
So listening to that value you know that if toggleDiv it's true you get display: inline if it's false you get display: none